# XGboost error while training a model on multi class classification "SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class)"

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, dask, xgboost

I am using the dask XGboost library (`xgboost.dask.DaskXGBClassifier`) to train a model on the data which has multiple classes. The classes are the following {1,2,3,4,5,6,21,25}. While fitting the classifier with `multi:softprob` objective, I am getting the following error `SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class)`. Interesting thing is, I have also train the model earlier with xgboost classifier but without dask (xgboost.XGBClassifier) but this issue did not occur. What could be the reason? [I am using xgboost==1.5.0 version]

I have used encodings to keep the labels within [0, num_class) but I have huge dataset and I think loading the data in memory and encoding the labels will results in memory issue which I want to avoid, which is the only reason I am aligning to dask library.

How to solve the issue?
The following is the sample code

```
def main(client):
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    ddf = dd.read_csv(df_path)

    # drop non numerical data, NaN, Inf, and position-specific data
    data = ddf.drop(discarded_columns, axis=1, errors='ignore')
    
    data = data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()

    train_x = data.drop(['prediction'], axis=1)
    train_y = data['prediction']

    from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
    (train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y) = train_test_split(
        train_x, train_y, test_size=TEST_SIZE,
        random_state=RANDOM_STATE
    )

    try:
        import xgboost as xgb
        print("Creating Classifier: ")
        
        classifier = xgb.dask.DaskXGBClassifier(client, random_state=RANDOM_STATE, n_jobs=-1, verbosity=1)

        # predefined tuned hyperparameters
        tuned_params = {
            'colsample_bytree': 0.8, 'eval_metric': 'mlogloss', 'gamma': 0,
            'learning_rate': 0.15, 'max_depth': 8, 'min_child_weight': 1,
            'n_estimators': 800, 'objective': 'multi:softprob', 'tree_method': 'hist'}
        print("Setting Params: ")
        classifier.set_params(**tuned_params)
        classifier.client = client
        print("Fitting the model: ")
        classifier.fit(train_x, train_y, eval_set=[(train_x, train_y)])
        bst = classifier.get_booster()
        history = classifier.evals_result()

        print("Evaluation history:", history)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
    with LocalCluster() as cluster:
        with Client(cluster) as client:
            main(client)
```

Comment: How does your `train_y` look like? It should contain integers in range [0, number_of_classes) representing each class. I guess you used the class indexes as given in description. Hower, there are 8 classes, not 25.

Comment: There are 8 classes with the following labels {1,2,3,4,5,6,21,25}. The train_y contains any one of these integers. As per the error, xgboost would like to have the labels by mapping the original labels to  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. This was required in xgboost classifier dask implementation, but not with the xgboost classifier as mentioned in the question. I have tested it by sample of data by encoding to [0, num_class) which works, but my data is huge and I want other way to achieve the same without having any memory issue.